# Read EAN codes with Titanium+ Barcode module?

Tags: module, titanium, barcode, appcelerator, barcode-scanner

Does Titanium+ Barcode module support EAN codes?
I have found very little documentation about the module. I can only get it to work with QR-codes, but I have to be able to read EAN codes in my app.
If it does, could someone please reply with a code example?

Comment: I've solved this problem. All you had to do is to hold the camera in landscape mode and it will capture the ean code. Took awhile to figure it out haha. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using "tibar" module. It supports the following symbols including EAN.
It's free and pretty fast on recognition.

http://code.google.com/p/tibar/

- QR-Code
- CODE-128
- CODE-39
- I25
- DataBar
- DataBar-Exp
- EAN-13
- EAN-8
- UPC-A
- UPC-E
- ISBN-13
- ISBN-10
- PDF417